# Espresso Libre theme for MacVim?

Tags: macos, software, themes, macvim

I recently changed editors from [TextMate](http://macromates.com) to [MacVim](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php). Thanks in part to `vimtutor`, things are going pretty well. But I miss the Espresso Libre color scheme:

[image: Espresso Libre Clone]

Is there a place where I can get Espresso Libre as a MacVim theme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the TextMate theme file, you can use this online converter to spit out a (Mac)Vim theme file for you: http://coloration.sickill.net/

It should do a pretty good job of converting it for you, as it did for the ones I've tried.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably be able to find something quite similar if not identical using [vimcolorschemetest](http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest)

Answer (score -2):

This what you're looking for? http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=45

Comment: That's for Eclipse, not MacVim.